# Clarification on "Inexperienced with computers, did I accidentally upload my files to the internet"

Tags: google-chrome

I accidentally dragged a screenshot file onto the internet. I was relieved to read the answer to Charles question "Did I aqccidentally upload my files on to the internet?" which was:

"No, you did not. Chrome only displayed the folder locally,..."

The screenshot I accidentally uploaded did indeed have file:/// in front of it, so it was displayed locally. But I'm still worried. If it's "displayed locally," does that mean it's on my Google Drive account? I don't see the file there. Is there any chance that this file is accessible by anyone on the internet?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When a URL has the prefix "file:///", all that means is that Chrome is loading it from your local computer.

It is not uploaded to your Google Drive account, or any other internet site, for that matter. Nobody can access it except you and those with access to your computer.

Comment: Whew! I know it says, "Don't say thanks," but thank you very much! I was freaking out.

Comment: You're welcome :) Please click on the check mark on my answer to mark it as the correct answer.